# How to derive an analogue of the covariance matrix for standard deviation?

Tags: linear-algebra, variance, covariance, standard-deviation

The covariance matrix can be interpreted as a summarization of a whole dataset into a single matrix representing a quadratic form that computes the variance of that dataset in a certain direction. I realize one might answer my question by: "you can compute std. dev. as $\sqrt{x^T\Sigma x}$", but I am not looking for a way to *compute* the standard deviation per se, I am looking for a way how to *derive* a summarization of the dataset (similar to what the covariance matrix is for computing variance) that will allow me to do this.

Let's say I don't know that covariance matrices exist and let's say I want to find a way how to compute the average value of standard deviation of a dataset $X = \left\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N | x_i \in \mathbb{R}^N\right\}$ in the direction given by a unit vector $d$. Assume that the dataset $X$ has been de-meaned. This is how I would go about computing it:

$$\text{std}(d) = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_i = |x_i \cdot d|$$

Writing a similar function for the variance and simplifying the expression yields the covariance matrix, which is a compressed representation of the whole dataset for the purposes of computing variance in arbitrary direction (and I'm comfortable with this derivation). How can I derive a similar compressed representation (not necessarily a matrix) of the whole dataset, but for computation of the standard deviation? Does such compressed representation even exist?

Or does such compressed representation exist **only** when we square the dot product (= the covariance matrix in this case)? Why is squaring so special? Why cannot we use any other symmetric functions like $x^4$ or $exp(|x|)$ to arrive at a summarization of a whole dataset for to purposes of computing **a** measure of spread (not necessarily variance)?

Comment: If covariance matrix $M$ is like a $\sigma^2$, are you asking what $\sigma$ could be in matricial terms ? If yes, an answer could be : the Cholesky matrix $C$,  is "the" (upper triangular) matrix such that $M=C^TC$ which exists for all positive-definite matrices. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.co.m/a/214408/147896).

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you. I view the matrix $C$ as an analogue of square root for a matrix, which, although it somehow makes sense, for me, it is still a "hand-wavy" analogue. To continue in your example: what I would like to know is how to *derive* **a** matrix "$C$" from basic principles: similarly like I'm able to derive (decompose or "factor-out", if you will) the covariance matrix from this expression $\frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i ( x_i \cdot d )^2$. You showed how to arrive at $C$ by first knowing $M$, but I want to derive "$C$" directly, such that $\sigma = f(C, x)$.

Comment: Maybe by successive decorellations (it is a way of explaining what Cholesky matrix "is" probabilisticaly speaking) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I apologize, I am not well-versed in mathematics, and so I am not sure what is meant by "successive decorellations". Is it related to [this Wikipedia topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorrelation)?

Comment: In fact, it is more probability than mathematics. Better see Wikipedia topic : ["whitening"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation) which is related to Cholesky decomposition of the **inverse** of variance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a matrix $A$ which satisfies $A^TA = \Sigma$ I think. Notice how
$$
\|Ax\|^2 = x^T A^TA  x = x^T \Sigma x
$$
i.e. $\|Ax\| = \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x}$

#### Covariance Reconstruction

Let $Y=(Y_1,\dots, Y_n)$ be a random vector of centered ($\mathbb{E}[Y_i]=0$) random variables with covariance zero and variance $1$, i.e.
$$
   \mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_j] = \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    0 & i\neq j\\
    1 & i=j
   \end{cases}
$$
Let us now consider $X=A^T Y$. $X$ is still centered, so
$$
\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) 
= \mathbb{E}[(A^T Y)_i (A^TY)_j]
= \mathbb{E}[(A^TYY^T A)_{ij}] = (A^T \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[YY^T]}_{\mathbb{I}}A)_{ij} = (A^T A)_{ij} = \Sigma_{ij}
$$
So $X$ has now covariance $\Sigma$. At the same time $(A^T)^{-1} X = Y$ is uncorrelated and standardized. This is the "whitening" that was mentioned in the comments

#### Normal distribution

If you have a standard normal distributed random variable $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $X:=\sigma Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Similarly for an iid standard normal vector $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I})$ we have that $X= A^T Y \sim\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$.

#### A is not unique

there are different $A$ which satisfy the equation $A^T A = \Sigma$.

1. Restricting ourselves to triangular matrices $A$: [Cholesky Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)
2. [Spectral Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices): Find an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) $U$ (i.e. $U^{-1} = U^T$) such that
   $$
   \Sigma = U D U^T
   $$
   where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. For a diagonal matrix it is easy to define $\sqrt{D}$ (entry-wise) and then you can define $A=U\sqrt{D}$.
   In essense this implies: take your iid normal vector $Y$, scale them by the standard deviations $\sqrt{d_i}$ where $d_i$ are the diagonal of $D$. And then rotate this resulting vector by $U$.